# Is there a way to use Thrust to set flag based on vector of indices

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, thrust

Suppose I have a array  A[0,2,4,5,6,7]

I want to transform it to B:

B [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1]

So A represent the indices of which element in B needs to be set to 1. A is sorted.

The maximum number in array A is known so that the size of B is known beforehand.

Is there a simple way to call Thrust library to accomplish this?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in one line in thrust:

```
#include <thrust/iterator/constant_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/permutation_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

  int A[6] = {0,2,4,5,6,7};
  int B[7] = {0};

  const int count_A = 6;

  thrust::copy(thrust::make_constant_iterator(1), thrust::make_constant_iterator(1)+count_A, thrust::make_permutation_iterator(B,A));

  thrust::copy(B, B+7, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 0 1 0 1 1 1
```